# Выделить строки, содержащие одно и тоже слово

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Приветствую! может кто-то знает как из большого текста( здесь конфига железки) выделить все строки(они всегда идут подряд), в которых есть уникальный идентификатор(слово).Но заранее мне это слово неизвестно. В моем случае это **"rtsp-video"**, **cust-udp**,  **comfone app**. То есть как бы получился бы список блоков из строк.

например получить такое:

```
set service "rtsp-video" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 80-80 
set service "rtsp-video" + udp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 554-554 
set service "rtsp-video" + tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 554-554 
set service "cust-udp" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 80-80 
set service "cust-udp" + udp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 554-554 
set service "cust-udp" + tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 554-554 
set service "cust-udp" + udp src-port 554-554 dst-port 0-65535 
set service "comfone app" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 12011-12011 
set service "comfone app" + tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 33333-33333
```

Подправьте ,пожалуйста, код:

```
        ................................... 
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(opendialog.FileName);
 string patternService = @"(set service "".+""){1,}.*";
 var matchesService = Regex.Matches(reader.ReadToEnd(), patternService);

      foreach (Match match in matchesService)
           {

                lst_app.Add(match.ToString());

           }
        }

        return lst_app;
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужны именно регекспы? Из условия "в которых есть уникальный идентификатор(слово)" это вообще никак не следует.

Comment: @vlazarev: обновил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте LINQ.

```
return File.ReadLines(opendialog.FileName)
           .Where(l => l.Contains("set service \"rtsp-video\""))
           .ToList();
```

Регулярки не нужны.

---

Для случая, когда нужно искать несколько строк:

```
return File.ReadLines(opendialog.FileName)
           .Where(l => strings.Any(s => l.Contains(s)))
           .ToList();
```

(где `strings` — список искомых подстрок).

---

Окей, подытоживая дискуссию в комментариях, вот решение. Всё же с регуляркой, ибо лень сканировать строку вручную.

```
var re = new Regex("set service \"(.*?)\"", // матчим обязательно нежадно.
                   RegexOptions.Compiled);
var groups = 
        from line in File.ReadLines(opendialog.FileName)
        from Match match in re.Matches(line)
        let innertext = match.Groups[1].Value
        group line by innertext into g
        select g;
return groups.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Возвращает `Dictionary`, отображающий ключ (`"rtsp-video"` и т. п.) в список строк, содержащих этот ключ.

Comment: @vlazarev: Вы имеете в виду

    l.Contains("set service \"rtsp-video\"")

?

Comment: ну да спасибо!

Comment: @vlazarev: Пожалуйста! Подправил ответ.

Comment: А как быть если мне не только блок строк с "rtsp-video", а нужны несколько блоков строк, заранее неизвестно сколько , в которых вместо "rtsp-video" будет , что-то еще "rtsp-audio"....! Вот где получается нужны регулярки! а как тут?

Comment: Оффтоп
Люк! Используй LINQ:)

Comment: @vlazarev: обновил ответ.

Comment: Думаю, что немного нет у нас взаимопонимания.Ну должны быть регулярки.только как и где?То Мне надо, чтобы код мог из такого текста(в моем вопросе,добавил) четко отделял блоки строк(то есть блок из 2х или 3х и т. д. строк). Но эти строки объединены в один блок по одному идентифицирующему признаку -все начинаются на set service "что-нибудь". Мне неизвестно ,что в кавычках внутри. Получится список этих блоков,который я далее буду использовать в цикле foreach, и с каждым в отдельности работать.

Comment: @vlazarev: Если можно сделать без регулярок — надо делать без, они жутко медленные и жрут очень много памяти. Ну да ладно. Тогда опишите в точности задачу. Я правильно понял — вам нужно (1) найти все строки, содержащие `set service "%"`, где на месте `%`стоит произвольный текст, и (2) сгруппировать найденные строки по значению этого самого текста?

Comment: Все верно! Именно так!